# Url problem: zend navigation appends routes to url - How to modify zend navigation default rendering

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I have reedited the question to show where was the problem.

> Hi, 
>   I'm building an cms application with Zend Framework. Everything works fine except for the >urls. When I click on a link that points to:
>
> ```
> 'dep/open/id/001'
> ```
>
> I effectively get there but the link text is appended to the url. If I now hover on >another link I can see in the status bar:
>
> 'dep/open/id/dep/open/id/023'
>
> and so on.
>
> I can't edit the urls because it's Zend_Navigation which is rendering them.
>
> How can I modify this?
>
> Thanks

**The problem** was that I was giving Zend_Navigation wrong uris:

```
public function renderAction()
{
    ...

        //THIS IS WRONG:
        $uri =  'dep/show/id/' . $dep->dept_id;
        ...

        $itemArray[] = array(
                    'label' =>$label,
                   'uri' => $uri
                   );
    }
    $container = new Zend_Navigation($itemArray);
        $this->view->navigation()->setContainer($container);
}
```

The uri should be :

```
 $uri = $dep->dept_id;
```

I think this may be because I have set a route for 'dep'

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'dep/show/:id',
        array(
            'action' => 'show',
            'controller' => 'dep',
            'module' => 'default',
            'id' => '',
            ),
        array( 
            'id' => '[0-9]+'
            )
        ); 

        $router->addRoute('dep', $route);
```

Could that be the reason?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first reedition of the question I have continued experimenting with the routes and the parameters passed to Zend_Navigation and I have come to the coclusion that actually the problem was that I had already set the 'dep' route to:

```
'/dep/show/id'
```

so passing the same route in the $uri parameter to Zend_Navigation produced the duplication problem.

It seems that I don't find solutions until I post questions here
Thank you all for your patience

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the issue is that you are supplying a *relative* url:

`$uri =  'dep/show/id/' . $dep->dept_id;`

So it's actually the *browser* that is screwing you up, interpreting that url *relative* to the current url.

If you create your url with a base url prefix:

`$uri =  'http://example.com/myapp/dep/show/id' . $dep->dept_id;`

or even:

`$uri =  '/myapp/dep/show/id' . $dep->dept_id;`

then the browser will treat those as absolute (respectively root-absolute) and you should be in better shape.

Note that the `baseUrl()` is available from the front controller.

Comment: Thank you David, after the first reedition of the question I have continued experimenting with the routes and the parameters passed to Zend_Navigation and I have come to the coclusion that actually the problem was that I had already set the 'dep' route to '/dep/show/id' so passing the same route to Zend_Navigation produced the duplication problem.

Comment: Aaah, gotcha. Glad that you found the issue. Cheers!